# Accessing resource files in a java jigsaw module

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, resources, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to access a file in my eclipse project from a class within the project. I need to declare the project as a jigsaw module to reach it from other projects, however by doing this, I no longer have access to files like "example.png" within the project.

This is my project structure:

```
project/
  module-info.java
  src/
    ...                   # trying to access files from here
  rsc/
    icons/
      example.png         # this is the file I need
    other-example.png
```

My module-info.java looks like this:

```
module dice_engine {
    exports com.packages.in.src;

    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.logging;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
}
```

And I try reading the file like this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/example.png")
```

Note that

1. I added the rsc directory as a source-folder to build path in eclipse
2. This was possible before creating the module-info.java
3. other-example.png is still accessible

Comment: By the way I suppose the compiler doesn't include packages without .java files when building the module (Although that doesn't explain why it worked when it wasn't a module). My question is just: What is the correct way to read the file then?